# Data is visible in Docker container + named volume although it shouldn't

Tags: docker

I'm probably just being stupid here, but I thought this shouldn't work, yet it does and I don't get why. I'm coping test files to /var/www in my Docker image during build and subsequently mounting a named volume on /var/www, but I still see the files.

```
~/test$ tree
.
├── docker
│   ├── data
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    ├── testfile1
    └── testfile2

3 directories, 4 files
```

`./docker/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  test-data:
    container_name: test-data
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/data/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - test-data:/var/www
volumes:
  test-data:
    name: test-data
```

`./docker/data/Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine

COPY src/ /var/www/

CMD sleep infinity
```

From what I thought I understand the volume isn't available at build time and should overlay/hide the files as it's mounted on /var/www too when the container starts, but it doesn't?

```
~/test$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' test-data
[{volume test-data /var/lib/docker/volumes/test-data/_data /var/www local rw true }]

~/test$ docker exec test-data ls -l /var/www
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 09:01 testfile1
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 09:01 testfile2
```

Running Docker Destop 3.6.0 on Windows + WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first time (only) a Docker named volume (only) is attached to a container, Docker copies files from the underlying image into the volume.  The volume contents never get updated after this initial copy.  This copy also doesn't happen for host-directory bind-mounts, or on Kubernetes or other not-actually-Docker environments.

You'd see the behavior you expect in two ways.  First, if you change the `volumes:` to a bind mount

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./local-empty-directory:/var/www
```

you'll see that replace the image content the way you expect.  The other thing you can change is to run your existing setup once, change the contents of the image, and run it again

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm test-data ls -l /var/www
touch src/testfile3
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm test-data ls -l /var/www
# testfile3 isn't in the volume and won't be in this listing
```

With its limitations, I tend to not recommend actually relying on the "Docker copies files into volumes" behavior.  There are a couple of common patterns that use it, but then are surprised when the volume never gets updated or the setup doesn't run in a different container runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally missed that, but with that info I now also found it in the docs.
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container

Answer (score 0):

Docker volumes exists independently of your image/container. If you run `docker volume ls` you will see your volumes, which is where the data exists and becomes mounted to the container at run-time